# Include stack template into another one

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I know that I can export values of some stacks via [Cross Stack References](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloudformation-update-yaml-cross-stack-references-simplified-substitution/). I also know that it's possible to reuse some code using [Nested Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html).

How can I have a template **routing-server.yml** and **ws-server.yml** and import (OR compose them in) **env-staging.yml**?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the reference architecture of the `awslabs/ecs-refarch-cloudformation` Github repository, it uses nested stacks.

```
Resources:

VPC:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
        TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ecs-refarch-cloudformation/infrastructure/vpc.yaml
        Parameters:
            EnvironmentName:    !Ref AWS::StackName
            VpcCIDR:            10.180.0.0/16
            PublicSubnet1CIDR:  10.180.8.0/21
            PublicSubnet2CIDR:  10.180.16.0/21
            PrivateSubnet1CIDR: 10.180.24.0/21
            PrivateSubnet2CIDR: 10.180.32.0/21
```

https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-refarch-cloudformation